# How to fix drop-down responses document in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

Basically, I'm using version tracking to list down all edited document. When I see on notes, it's not created as a drop down and it just shows all record.

For example like this [website](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_10.0.1/basic/H_ABOUT_INDENTING_RESPONSE_DOCUMENTS.html). Provide by @umeli. But I can't seem to get it inside my lotus notes.

Like below this. I have this view inside my lotus notes. It just shows everything.
[image: notes]

This is list inside my browser. It has like drop-down when I click, it will show all.
[image: drop down]

Like this. When I click, it will show all the history of the edited document.
[image: all list]

Any advice that I can create a drop-down like in-browser inside my notes? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Domino Designer to edit the `No` column. You need to select the "Show twistie ..." setting as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_SETTING_STYLES_FOR_COLUMNS_OVER.html).

Also, you may want to automatically collapse the view entries when the user opens the database. To do that, edit the view properties and select "Collapse all when database is first opened".